# Python class doesn't work

Tags: python, class

When I run this code, it does get to the `_init_` function and I'm not sure why. I call it at the end with `hangman = Main()`, but it isn't working.

```
class Main:

    wordToGuess = 'world cup'
    displayWord = '***** ***'
    num_wrong = 0;    

    def _init_(self):
        print('lets play!')
        while True:
            letter = input('Enter guess: ')
            isDansWord = self.isInWord(letter)
            if isDansWord:
                self.updateDisplayWord(letter)
                print(self.displayWord)
                if self.checkForWin():
                    self.win()
                    break
                else:
                    print('wrong')
                    self.num_wrong += 1
                    if self.checkForLoss():
                        self.loss()
                        break

    def isInWord(self,letter):
        inWord = False
        for x in range(0, len(self.displayWord)):
            if self.wordToGuess[x:x + 1] == letter:
                inWord = True
                break
        return inWord

    def checkForWin(self):
        if self.wordToGuess == self.displayWord:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def checkForLoss(self):
        if self.num_wrong > 5:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def win(self):
        print('you win!')

    def loss(self):
        print('you lose!')

print('Hangman\n')

hangman = Main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need 4 underscores:

its `__init__`, not `_init_`

Answer (score 2):

The `__init__` method is a [*special method*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) in Python. Special methods begin and end with double underscores `__`, so your method should be:

```
def __init__(self):
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not `_init_`, but `__init__`(two "_" from each side).